# Java / Android rookie here, please help me

Tags: java, android

{@link android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever#METADATA_KEY_ARTIST}

What is happening above?

What does "@link" mean?

and why is there a #?  What does that # mean?

thanks a lot, experts @ Stack Overflow~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "@link" mean?

It means "put a link in the JavaDocs".

> and why is there a #? What does that # mean?

It means "the stuff to the right of the # is a member of the stuff to the left of the #"